# Show the text from EditText on ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I have a button, an editText, and a listView on my project. The function I want to realize is that as I enter some words in editText and click the button, the words I typed need to be in the listView.

Here is my code. After debugging, it shows `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]`

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] str = new String[10];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);  //build listview
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void sendMessage(View view){
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        str = editText.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is working code for what you want.

step 1 -> Add data in edit text

step 2 -> click on submit button

step 3 -> Added data will display in listview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);  //build listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        str.add(editText.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        editText.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);  //build listview
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void sendMessage(View view){
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String str1 = editText.getText().toString();
          str.add(str1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't work because there is no calling of sendMessage

Comment: This code will not work, without notifying data set change to adapter, list will not update.You must need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @Ashish : sendMessage() is calling from xml. This is very basic thing.you can call method from xml layout when button clicked.

Answer (score 1):

error `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]`
is because of `str = editText.getText().toString();`
here you are trying to assign string to array of string incorrectly

what you have to do is use `ArrayList` insted of `String[]` as it is dynamic and efficient than `String[]`

and

insted of `str = editText.getText().toString();` do
`arrayList.add(ditText.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 1):

> In your case you are using `String[]` array with size 10.
>   now if you want to add string from `EditText` in `ListView` then you have to add like below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] str = new String[10];
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);  //build listview
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void sendMessage(View view){
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if(count < str.length){
             str[count] = editText.getText().toString();
             count++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Why you geeting error?**

> You get the error because you set the String array as a string. But if you want to add string in string array then you have to specify a position for array.